# My App just got rejected from the App Store due to metadata. What is metadata within an app and where/how do you change it?

Tags: ios, app-store, metadata

2. 3 Performance: Accurate Metadata

Guideline 2.3 - Performance

We noticed that your app's metadata is not relevant to the app's content and functionality.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise or remove this content from your app's metadata.

Since your iTunes Connect status is Rejected, a new binary will be required. Make the desired metadata changes when you upload the new binary.

NOTE: Please be sure to make any metadata changes to all app localizations by selecting each specific localization and making appropriate changes.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going through this exact issue now with an app update. First, metadata means "data that describes data." In your app, your metadata is primarily the information (data) you see in the App Information and iOS App version tabs that describes what your app (binary data) does and what it looks like. The three things most likely to get you rejected are your app name, your keywords, or your screenshots / demo video. Apple reviewers are becoming über strict about this stuff.

[image]

I am now on my 2nd rejection. The first one they gave me was vague. They just said it had an inappropriate app name or keywords. I thought it was my keywords, so I got rid of ones that were search related. Rejected!

This time they gave me more info. This is from the review team:

> Guideline 2.3.7 - Performance
>
> Your app name to be displayed on the App Store includes keywords or
>   descriptors, which are not appropriate for use in an app name.
>
> Specifically, the following words in your app name are considered
>   keywords or descriptors:
>
> “楽しく覚えよう！よく出る 1750 TOEIC 英単語と発音練習”
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app name to remove any
>   keywords and descriptors from all localizations of your app. Keywords
>   can be entered in the Keywords field in iTunes Connect to be used as
>   search terms for your app.
>
> Please also remember to re-evaluate your app name title to ensure it’s
>   50 characters or less.

I'm not sure why they chose the Japanese localization as the example...maybe that is what set off their alarms. The way I interpret this is that not only has Apple decided that app names are to be 50 characters or less, but anything in the name that is not...well...the actual name, is grounds for rejection. I'm going to try again. I'll let you know if it passes with follow up information in a few days. Good luck!

**UPDATE** -- App approved!
The issue with my app was the app name. The name got through this 3rd iteration. I didn't put the app name above, but as it's pertinent here, the actual app name is "TOEIC Flash." It's basically a vocabulary memorization app. For a few years, the name has been "TOEIC Flash - Easily learn 1750 TOEIC words!" That "selly" name seems to have been the problem. My guess is that the app store wants a factual name, and just the facts -- no SEO oriented keywords or app name extensions. The name that was accepted was: 
"TOEIC Flash - TOEIC Vocab Memorization System"
 Boring and straight to the point. But it made it through. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 1):

An app's metadata is that information you enter for the app on the iTunes Connect page for the app.  Metadata includes such things as age range (to gauge suitability for children), keywords, contact information, etc.  Just as a guess, I think the keywords you've chosen for the app, in the reviewer's opinion, do not match "the  app's content and functionality". But, I could be wrong; it could be an entirely different field within your submitted metadata.

I'm not sure what the note about localizations refer to.  Do you have localization defined for your app?

Comment: I do not know what localizations are.... so i would assume that i have not defined any.

Comment: Localizations are the files you add to your app that are the translations and equivalences that will allow your app to appear in the language of a locality -- for example, French in France, Spanish in Spain, etc. It's quite an involved process.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. My screenshots are containing the test flight word on the top left. I have fixed these issues. I hope the app will be approved.